# Can VB.NET create inline blocks with new scope?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, scope, c#-to-vb.net

In C#, one can create a new scope by simply placing some braces around code. For example:

```
{
    Foo fooA = new Foo();
    fooA.doSomething();
    fooA.doSomethingElse();
}

{
    // Can't refer to fooA in here.
    Foo fooB = new Foo();
    fooB.doSomething();
    fooB.doSomethingElse();
}
```

Does VB.NET have a way to create a new scope without using any reserved words?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (nowhere near as elegant as the C# code, but does the same job):

```
    If True Then
        Dim fooA As New Foo()
        fooA.doSomething()
        fooA.doSomethingElse()
    End If

    If True Then
        ' Can't refer to fooA in here.
        Dim fooB As New Foo()
        fooB.doSomething()
        fooB.doSomethingElse()
    End If
```

I would have to question *why* you would want to do this though...refactoring jumps out to me

Comment: I don't think braces without a control structure is particularly elegant, so I'd say this VB code is *as* elegant as the C# code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the "without using any reserved words" requirement isn't really fair, as VB.Net uses words instead of braces. Put another way, C# braces are really just words (tokens) in disguise.

That said, VB.Net can't do it exactly the way C# does. You need some specific type of code block for this. For example, it's easy enough to just include that code in an `If` block that's always true:

```vb
If True Then
    '...
End If
```

The above amounts to pretty much the same thing, and probably (untested) works out to nearly the same IL as the C#, in that I'd expect the compiler to optimize away any actual boolean test.

In this case, though, since both blocks do just about the same thing, I'd be tempted to abstract that code out to it's own method anyway. If you really want, you could even use an Action or Func delegate to keep everything in the existing local method and still avoid code duplication.